# Caching Objects

Tags: c#, .net

I just had a need to cache information for a part of the application to improve performance.  Now automatically I looked at the `System.Runtime.Caching` namespace.  Ok all looks good except it uses strings.

I don't want to use strings for the obvious reason someone mistyping somewhere a key and duplicating cache entries by mistake.

Now of course I can subclass it make all it's string based methods throw a `NotImplementedException` and create strongly typed methods instead.

I am thinking of create a class like so `CustomMemoryCache<TKey, TValue>`

Now before I go ahead and do this I want to make sure:

A.  There isn't already an implementation that does this and I have missed it or an open source project that does this already.

B.  There is a very good reason not to do this.

Comment: What platform are you developing for?  Web?  Desktop?  Silverlight?  Windows 8?

Comment: So what *are* you going to use as a key?  Frequently this is solved by just having a class with a bunch of constants representing cache keys.  If you want to use something else, how do you plan to get an instance of that something else that's specific to the logical key you need?

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't let users type in the keys.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Even if it's programmers hard coding them at compile time there can still be typos, hence my suggestion to use constants in code.

Comment: Yes, and for programmers there are tools to help get it right. So my argument stands: strings as keys is fine.

Comment: i am guessing the caching is user specific information, not global application information. For those cases on the web side of things, I have used the name of the page, the method being called and the information to be cached as a pipe delimited cache key. Never had a key problem.

Comment: What is the scenario that use user would enter the key.  And you can check the cache if that key exists.

Comment: My scenario is the developers remembering correctly and it's not specific to a UI it is in the business layer of the application.  My thoughts are using an enum for the Key as this will show all available keys for the cache quickly hence creating my custom cache.  Consts would certainly work as well but then it's remembering which constants are for the cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I did create a new cache class that accepted generics for its keys and the caches are initialized with an enum so the developer is limited to certain keys.

Unfortunately I can not provide the code as it's in a closed source project.

Comment: You could have simply gotten the string name of the `enum` with `System.Runtime.Caching`. Writing your own cache system is rarely worth while as the number of gotchas are pretty staggering. If you really wanted to protect the keys though you could have made a wrapper class for `System.Runtime.Caching` that handled the naming via an `enum`.

Comment: @siva.k That is exactly what I did I created a wrapper class that exposed an interface very similar to the existing caching system.  The wrapper accepts a normal system caching object in as a parameter.